# Unable to mount usb drive in bash (ubuntu server)

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab

I am unable to mount my USB drive in the bash. First, I formated it with parted:

```
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdc
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mkpart
Partition name?  []? backup
File system type?  [ext2]? ext4
Start? 1m
End? 100%
(parted) q
```

Then, I obtained the UUID of the partition:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1: PARTLABEL="backup" PARTUUID="29e0527b-b182-46ff-b8d4-b457f2cbd19c"
```

Next, I put the PARTUUID into /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=96a4c1cc-8681-45a9-b3f7-634803e2c6fa /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=29e0527b-b182-46ff-b8d4-b457f2cbd19c /media/backup1        ext4    noauto,defaults 0       2
```

So far so good. However, mounting does not work:

```
sudo mount /media/backup1
mount: can't find UUID=29e0527b-b182-46ff-b8d4-b457f2cbd19c
```

So, mount does not seem to find this UUID. But it is there, I can still query it with `sudo blkid /dev/sdc1`. Also, `sudo fdisk -l` also seems to find it:

```
sudo fdisk -l

[...]    

Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 732566646 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 66AC3C98-AAF8-4E3B-90F3-2813B52F69DA

Device     Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1    256 732566527 732566272  2.7T Linux filesystem
```

One interesting thing I noted is that the entry is not in `blkid` but only in `sudo blkid`:

```
blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="96a4c1cc-8681-45a9-b3f7-634803e2c6fa" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d02d7331-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="datapool" UUID="7111675423553490798" UUID_SUB="13772573515660158653" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-6e73ce37d37e2e96" PARTUUID="f46820b7-8b06-f947-bdad-c63d50404137"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="datapool" UUID="7111675423553490798" UUID_SUB="11975018375513471305" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-ab8eb30bd084e717" PARTUUID="d29dadab-f6e7-dd4a-b7d6-442544920142

sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="96a4c1cc-8681-45a9-b3f7-634803e2c6fa" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d02d7331-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="datapool" UUID="7111675423553490798" UUID_SUB="13772573515660158653" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-6e73ce37d37e2e96" PARTUUID="f46820b7-8b06-f947-bdad-c63d50404137"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="datapool" UUID="7111675423553490798" UUID_SUB="11975018375513471305" TYPE="zfs_member" PARTLABEL="zfs-ab8eb30bd084e717" PARTUUID="d29dadab-f6e7-dd4a-b7d6-442544920142"
/dev/sda9: PARTUUID="403ede0a-5e26-4244-8a0c-5de2f00e2526"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="d02d7331" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sdb9: PARTUUID="91eb1b79-fc3d-6847-9b52-c2f46d04b7c6"
/dev/sdc1: PARTLABEL="backup" PARTUUID="29e0527b-b182-46ff-b8d4-b457f2cbd19c"
```

**UPDATE:**
Okay, now I managed to get rid of the above error by using `PARTUUID=` instead of `UUID=`. However, now I get the following error:

```
sudo mount /media/backup1/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

The output of `dmesg | tail` is as follows:

```
[ 3349.566573] EXT4-fs (sdc1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

What is the problem now?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo dmesg | tail` (as suggested in the error message) just after trying to mount the file system?

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I have appended the output.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this is all the output of the above command (`tail` prints the last 10 lines of its input by default). That one line is a hint but some more context would be very helpful.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: You are right, but all other lines had a much older time stamp, so they were from before the execution of the command. I therefore omitted them.

Comment: Just to exclude some stuff, could you please try to run `sudo mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/29e0527b-b182-46ff-b8d4-b457f2cbd19c /media/backup1`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you disconnect/reconnect the USB drive or reboot the machine since you partitioned the drive and created the file system? If not please run

```
sudo partprobe /dev/sdc
```

to tell the kernel to update its information about the partition table and file system UUIDs on the drive.

Comment: I tried this and it didin't help. Also, rebooting didn't help.

Comment: Okay, fixed the problem, now another problem. See above.